# VBA Automation - Downloading a file using IE 11 (64bit)

Tags: vba, automation

This question seems to have been asked dosens of times, however none of the solutions I have found seem to be able to solve my problem.

As the webpage is using a certificate token I am forced to log on to the webpage manually before I can activate the VBA script, which is no problem. An important note is that the link to the report is dynamic and therefore I cannot link directly to the report itself and therefore I have to navigate the webpage with my Script. Below you find the script i am using to locate the window I have logged on to the webpage with:

```
Sub WebPageOpen()

Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

On Error GoTo Err_Clear

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For X = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(X).document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(X).document.Title

    If my_title Like "MY Webpage name" Then 'compare to find if the desired web page is already open
        Set IE = objShell.Windows(X)
        marker = 1
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next

If marker = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Webpage is not open - Please log on to webpage")
    Exit Sub
Else
End If

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

' I have removed all my navigation commands here,as it would just be bloating the query. It clicks the link and the Save/open ribbon appears in IE.

End sub
```

Can anyone help me with some sort of solution to how I can interact with the Open/Save as ribbon which appears when I download the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ribbon is called ***Notification bar.***

You can use Alt+N to focus on the Notification Bar. And then send {tab} key to navigate to the specific button.

With VBA, you may use Autohotkey.dll or AutoItX3.dll to send these hotkey combinations.

1. Add reference to AutoItX3.dll (for both 32-bit and 64-bit OS)
2. Append the following

   set X=CreateObject("AutoItX3.Control")
   X.send !N{tab}{down 2}{enter}  'This is for Save-as